# Getting Invalid Argument Error while loading Bing map in my site?

Tags: asp.net, bing-maps

I am using Bing map in my website and displaying some points on it while a user search using some keyword. But when there is no result i am getting a javascript error in veapidelay.js this is Bing map javascript. I am getting Invalid Argument error on line "e.style.width=this.getActualWidth().toFixed()+"px"".
Do anyone know what can be the possible issue?

I am using ASP.Net as technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` fixed this problem for me in IE9. IE8 still gives me the same error though.